# How can I trigger an icon in the notification area from cmd / powershell / .bat?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell, notification-area

I have a Windows 10 OS where the notification area (bottom left corner) is inaccessible to the user. There are some programs running there that I would like to be able to launch without being able to click them. Does anyone know how to invoke or trigger icons that are sitting in the notification area to launch them without clicking them, preferably through command prompt or powershell?

I tried launching the .exe for these programs directly, but when I do this, it just adds another instance to the notification area instead of actually launching the application.

Comment: You cannot generate a Windows 10 notification in Powershell.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730952.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 has a comprehensive how-to on how to show notifications. It uses .NET [System.Reflection.Assembly]. Hope this helps. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: If you wanted to use something non-native to the OS you could use AutoIT or AutoHotkey. There may be a way using .Net to perform the same task but a quick search doesn't show anyone attempting to access notifications via Powershell.

Comment: You seem to be under a lot of misapprehension. The icon in the notification area isn't a shortcut. It is the program itself. What happens when you click on it entirely depends on the program code. You don't launch programs when you click on them; the program just shows its window.

Unless the program lets you, you can't do much from Command Prompt.

Answer (score 1):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730952.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 has a comprehensive how-to on how to show notifications. It uses .NET [System.Reflection.Assembly].

It depends on the programs running. The .NET class System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon is what runs this area.This is a shortcut to the .exe From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon(v=vs.110).aspx there are multiple options that are available depending on how the app is written.

Icons in the notification area are shortcuts to processes that are running in the background of a computer, such as a virus protection program or a volume control. These processes do not come with their own user interfaces. The NotifyIcon class provides a way to program in this functionality. The Icon property defines the icon that appears in the notification area. Pop-up menus for an icon are addressed with the ContextMenu property. The Text property assigns ToolTip text. In order for the icon to show up in the notification area, the Visible property must be set to true.

Comment: This lets a PowerShell script create a notification area icon, but the question asked how to activate or simulate a click on an existing notification area icon. Also, please note that we prefer answers that are as self-contained as possible, since links can break and external pages can change.

Comment: Sorry, am on holidays and only have mobile access. Will update over the next week once I'm back fully online. Apologies for only providing the link.